# Getting Null Values while passing data with intent from adapter to activity

Tags: java, android

This is probably a very basic question but I couldn't find the answer.

I need to pass data from RecyclerView but when I check it on related activity, data is null.

```
mvHolder.barcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent s = new Intent(context, SummaryActivity.class);
        s.putExtra("SUMMARY",sp.getDATA().get(i).getId_summary()); // data is not null
        context.startActivity(s);
    }
});
```

and this is how I try to achieve it :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    strBarcode = extras.getString("SUMMARY");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

but when I debug it, it turns out that strBarcode is null. I don't know what the problem is, I guess my code should be works either. Please help me

Comment: What is the value you got on sp.getDATA().get(i).getId_summary()

Comment: it's an id for each row in recyclerview, it is from server @ShantoGeorge

Comment: `sp.getDATA().get(i).getId_summary()` must be string. If it is integer then `getString()` returns null

Comment: You should have to use Interface If you want to pass data to the related activity!

Comment: Did you try to pass some data put it directly: `s.putExtra("SUMMARY", "Some string");`?

Comment: got it, i've found the answer thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent data = getIntent();
if (data != null) {
    strBarcode = data.getStringExtra("SUMMARY");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

Comment: @Iganov Could you please update the question, preferable with a StackTrace?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `getIntent().hasExtra("SUMMARY") returns true`.
If it does, make sure that `sp.getDATA().get(i).getId_summary()` returns a `String`.

> The extra might be there, but you try to get as String, and it might
>   have different type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent data = getIntent();
if (data != null) {
   int strBarcode = data.getIntExtra("SUMMARY");
}
```

Please try this